# How to store Entry URL (Landing URL) and Referring site to a website using jquery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I want to store the **landing page url** to my website.

**example**: when user comes from the google search to http://mysite.com/, He can browse any number of pages But the landing url or entry url will be http://mysite.com/. So i was not able to store this url, but i can able to store the previous url using `document.referrer`. How to do this in jquery, Do i need to use cookies or Is there any other way.

**How to store the referring site**, For example if user comes from google search. how to store it, instead of storing the previous URL. Is this can be done using PHP.

Comment: [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) - The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to store it? If you want to store it in a server-side database, you can you Jquery to call an AJAX function to store it. 
Alternatively, you can use PHP using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

An other part of your question is how to not store your local pages, you can use regular expression, e.g.

```
$domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);   
$host = @$domain['host'];
if (!preg_match('/yourwebsite\.com/', $host)){
    // Store your url        
}
```

Hope it helps.